# Amazon VPC cannot SSL creticiate error for every download url

Tags: iptables, ssl-certificate

in Amazon VPC, i have one public subnet, having one NAT gateway, and one private subnet with 2 servers. i have enabled NAT (port forwarding ) of ports 80 and 443 to inside server to access a website present on one web server in private subnet.

Now when i try to wget any url or run yum update, i get following error:

> M2Crypto.SSL.Checker.WrongHost: Peer certificate subjectAltName does not match host, expected mirror.rightscale.com, got                                                 DNS:www.crowdprep.com, DNS:crowdprep.com

When i remove the iptables NAT rules from Prerouting table, i no more get this error. What is the relation of this error with the iptable rules?

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your NAT rule is redirecting all HTTPS traffic to some other host. I don't quite understand what your NAT rule is attempting to achieve, but try make it more specific (e.g. match source or destination port number instead of either, match a source or destination IP or subnet as appropriate).

Comment: Here are the rules: iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.10:80
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.10:443

Comment: i just had to add "-A PREROUTING ! 10.0.1.0/24..." which would not route the private subnet traffic.